# Openfaas function keeps returning the same result even after redeploying

Tags: openfaas

I built a little Openfaas function using the tutorial. After initial build and deployment, it worked just fine and returned `{"status":"done"}`, just as I intended.

After the initial successful run, I made changes to the `index.js` handler (it's a `node` project). I rebuilt and redeployed using the following commands:

`faas-cli build -f license.yml && faas-cli deploy -f license.yml`

and invoke the function using the following command:

`curl 127.0.0.1:8080/function/license -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"hosts":["YYYXXXAAABBBCCC"]}'`

In stead of returning a "status" object (see above), it should return a "licenseKey". However, no matter how often I build/deploy this function, it keeps returning the original object.

What do I have to do to make Openfaas use the new code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I made a rookie mistake. In stead of using `handler.js` as the main file I used `index.js`. I probably had a leftover `handler.js` from running the tutorial, but `mv index.js handler.js` did the trick (after rebuilding and deploying, of course).